# Decorators for zend captcha field

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha

I am trying to add captcha field on my from using zend form.

am using decorators:

```
> private $elementDecorators = array(  
> 'ViewHelper', 'Errors',
> array('errors',array('tag' => 'td',
> 'class' => 'error')),
>     array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'td' 
> ,'valign'=>'middle','align'=>'left')),
> array('Label', array('requiredSuffix' 
> => ' * ',
>               'tag' => 'td',
>                                    )),
>     array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' =>
> 'tr','class'=>'tr','openOnly'=>true,'align'=>'right')),
> );
```

Captcha field is working fine.but it's putting captcha field on top of page because of absence of a  `td`

can  any one explain what decorators we can use for captcha field so it will come at right place?

Comment: can you slow down, check your spelling and formulate a clearer question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use latest ZF version.
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9168